# How to make two screens show simultaneously like in snapchat?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am creating a camera roll feature similar to snapchat where the camera is the bottom layer and then after tapping a button the camera roll appears. The camera roll does not occupy the whole screen the search bar on the top is still maintained and upon dismissal with a swipe gesture down the camera is still running.  I am not sure how this affect is achieved. Is it done by using a scroll view or a segue of some kind? Thank you for your help.

Below is the video in question
[Snap Chat Camera Roll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yOxL.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this type of effect cannot be achieved using the standard camera *UIImagePickerController*. You will need to create your own camera view.
Here is a good guide to get you started: https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Camera-View

You could also try using a custom library that can be easily customized such as: https://github.com/omergul/LLSimpleCamera/

Now, in terms of the actual visual, I do not believe there is any actual segue/change of viewcontroller involved. The camera view is probably always on screen (except perhaps when it is fully covered by the Memories screen), it is simply overlayed by other things.

The Memories screen is most likely 'presented' in a custom manner. The show/dismissal logic can be achieved by attaching a *UIPanGestureRecognizer* to the *UIView* and translating the view up and down on pan event. If the pan's y value passes a certain threshold up or down, it automatically continues its animation to show or hide the view.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, Is the effect of this overlay sliding up and down best achieved using a scroll view or by using a regular view with animations involved?

Comment: How is the dismissal of the memories screen where it appears to be sliding down as it is swiped achieved?

Comment: I believe using a UIView with a UIPanGestureRecognizer as well UIView animations would be the best approach. The pan gesture would react to your slow scrolling with finger down, and then the animations would fire after the touch finishes, to fully show or fully hide the view.